# A* Pathfinding very slow

Tags: java, android, optimization, a-star

I wrote a pathfinding algorithm for android. It seems to be running very slowly and I can not figure out why. I have asked a similar question before, but I didn't get the answers I was looking for (And I have changed code since then). Here is my path finding class :

```
public class Pathfinding {

    private static Node[][] grid;

    private static NodeComparator nodeComparator;

    static{
        nodeComparator = new NodeComparator();
    }

    public static class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Node node1, Node node2) {

            if(node1.F > node2.F){
                return 1;
            }
            else if(node1.F < node2.F){
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }

        }
    }

    public static Array<Node> findPath(Node start, Node finish, Node[][] _grid) {

        Array<Node> path = new Array<Node>();
        Array<Node> openList = new Array<Node>();
        Array<Node> closedList = new Array<Node>();

        grid = _grid;

        if(start == null){

            return path;
        }
        if(finish == null){

            return path;
        }

        Node currentNode = start;
        currentNode.G = 0;
        currentNode.H = getHeuristic(currentNode, finish);
        currentNode.parent = null;
        openList.add(currentNode);

        System.out.println("PATHFINDING STARTED ||| startPos : " + start.position + " finishPos : " + finish.position);

        while (openList.size > 0) {

            //Sorts open nodes lowest F value to heighest
            openList.sort(nodeComparator);

            currentNode = openList.first();

            //If path is found, return
            if (currentNode == finish) {
                System.out.println("PATH FOUND...RETURNING -gat5");

                return constructPath(currentNode);
            }

            openList.removeValue(currentNode, true);
            closedList.add(currentNode);

            int counter = 0;
            for (Node neighbor : getNeighbors(currentNode)) {
                if (!closedList.contains(neighbor, true)) { //If neighbor not in closed list
                    if(neighbor != null) { //If neighbor not wall

                        if(counter == 4){
                            counter++;
                        }

                        int movementCost = checkMovementCost(counter);

                        if (openList.contains(neighbor, true)) {
                            if (currentNode.G + movementCost < neighbor.G) {
                                neighbor.parent = currentNode;
                            }
                        } else {
                            openList.add(neighbor);
                            neighbor.parent = currentNode;
                            neighbor.H = getHeuristic(currentNode, finish);
                            neighbor.G = neighbor.parent.G + movementCost;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(counter);

        }

        System.out.println("NO FINAL");
        System.out.println("NO PATH FOUND RETURNING...");
        path.add(start);
        return path;

    }

    private static int checkMovementCost(int neighbor) {
        int movementCost = 0;
        switch (neighbor) {
            //Diagonal
            case 0:
            case 2:
            case 6:
            case 8:
                movementCost = 16;
                break;
            //Not Diagonal
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
                movementCost = 10;
                break;
        }

        return movementCost;
    }

    public static Array<Node> constructPath(Node finish) {
        Array<Node> pathNodes = new Array<Node>();

        Node currentNode = finish;
        pathNodes.add(currentNode);

        while (currentNode.parent != null) {
            currentNode = currentNode.parent;
            pathNodes.add(currentNode);
        }

        return pathNodes;
    }

    private static float getHeuristic(Node start, Node finish){
        int H = 0;

        H += Math.abs(start.position.x - finish.position.x);
        H += Math.abs(start.position.y - finish.position.y);

        return H;
    }

    private static Array<Node> getNeighbors(Node node){
        Array<Node> neighbors = new Array<Node>();

        int x = (int)node.position.x;
        int y = (int)node.position.y;

        if(x - 1 > 0 && x - 1 < grid.length && y + 1 < grid.length && y + 1 > 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x - 1][y + 1]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }
        if(x > 0 && x < grid.length && y + 1 < grid.length && y + 1 > 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x][y + 1]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }
        if(x + 1 > 0 && x + 1 < grid.length && y + 1 < grid.length && y + 1 > 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x + 1][y + 1]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }


        if(x - 1 > 0 && x - 1 < grid.length && y < grid.length && y > 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x - 1][y]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }
        if(x > 0 && x < grid.length && y < grid.length && y > 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x][y]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }
        if(x + 1 > 0 && x + 1 < grid.length && y < grid.length && y > 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x + 1][y]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }


        if(x - 1 > 0 &&  x - 1 < grid.length && y - 1 < grid.length && y - 1> 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x - 1][y - 1]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }
        if(x > 0 && x < grid.length && y - 1 < grid.length && y - 1 > 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x][y - 1]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }
        if(x + 1 > 0 && x + 1 < grid.length && y - 1 < grid.length && y - 1 > 0){
            neighbors.add(grid[x + 1][y - 1]);
        }
        else{
            neighbors.add(null);
        }

        return neighbors;

    }

}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

**Some more information : ** When I run this algorithm only once, it works fine. But once I run it 3+ times, it starts lose framerate fast. My grid I am using is  200x200.

Comment: An explanation of the problem the algorithm tries to solve would be helpful. Otherwise it has to be reverse engineered from the program.

Comment: @Henry It is an a* pathfinding algorithm...

Comment: That's obvious, but what about the details? Where is the path searcherd for? Are all paths allowed? What is the cost of one step? ...

Comment: Btw. How is the question different from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142951/a-path-finding-algorithm-running-extremely-slow

Comment: @Henry Not to be rude, but if you're not going to be helpful, don't comment. I already explained above that my other question didn't get the answers I was looking for, not to mention my code has changed since then. As for the details, it is easy to see that 1) Up, Down, Left, Right movement is 10 cost, and diagonal is 16 (Most people who are familiar with the algorithm should know this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your evaluation of the paths is as simple as you are pointing out, probably the slowness of the algorithm has something do do with the ordering that you do in each iteration of the algorithm.

```
        //Sorts open nodes lowest F value to heighest
        openList.sort(nodeComparator);
```

Just using `PriorityQueue` to order the nodes to be expanded by the algorithm results in a much more efficient implementation. If you want, take a look to the implementation details of [the A* algorithm](https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/1.0.X/hipster-core/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/algorithm/AStar.java) implemented in the library [hipster4j](http://hipster4j.org). This works in Android, too.

Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Thanks a million! Worked like a charm.